# Cookie issue with Internet Explorer

Tags: cookie, windows, magento-1.9.2

I have an issue with my Magento installation (Version 1.9.2.2). It works in every browser (tested with Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Opera) but not in Internet Explorer.

In IE, Magento doesn't set any cookie. I can put an item in my cart and view my cart – and it's empty. Even the Cookie Law Compliance-cookie (when the user clicks "Accept") isn't set so you click on "Allow" and at another page, the message with Cookie Law which you have to accept is there again.

Here my settings for cookies in backend:
**Cookie Lifetime:** 86400
**Cookie Path:** /
**Cookie Domain:** ..de (my correct domain is inserted)
**Use HTTP only:** No
**Cookie Restriction Mode:** No

I have tried to set the "Use HTTP only" to Yes and it doesn't work. I've edited the Varien.php and it doesn't work. Magento sets cookies in every browser but not in IE.

Hope you understand my problem. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I had to turn on "accept all cookies in IE" and nothing lower than 9 seems to work for me.